# Delete all records Then what is left put into Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, sql-delete

Please advise. I've got a query 
(the @variables are local or parameters passed).

```
    Delete  a
    From    T_HISTORY a
    JOIN    #tempb ON a.p_no = b.p_no
    Where   a.run_date 
    between Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar, @run_date, 101)) and Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar, @run_date, 101) + ' 23:59:59') 
    and     value_don= @value_don
```

then we have a second query -- right after

```
        select  a.*
        into    #test_delete
        From    T_HISTORY  a
        JOIN    #tempb b ON a.p_no = b.p_no
        Where   a.run_date 
        between Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar, @run_date, 101)) and Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar, @run_date, 101) + ' 23:59:59') 
        and     value_don= @value_don
```

What the hope is -- is to take everything that is in the history table joined on the temp table and delete it if it falls between the run date `(00:00 - 23:59:59)` and the value_don is equal to our passed parameter.

Whatever is left after whatever wasn't' deleted, and its possible something wasn't. That data should be dropped into `a #test_delete`

Then the next line of code reads

```
    insert into LT_history_Audit_Log (  ... a bunch of columns ... )
    select      *
    From        #test_Delete
    Where       run_date between    Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar, @run_date, 101)) and Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar, @run_date, 101) + ' 23:59:59') 
    and         value_don= @value_don
```

So theoretically what should happen is we would have an occasional line of code, maybe a few entered into the audit_log table.

However, what i'm seeing happen is that every single line that is deleted in the first statement is entered into the `#test_delete` table.

The data in the history table is composed of values based on different parameters and run times. The temp table limits what we pull from the history table. Based on this criteria we want to remove these records. This means there could possibly be something in the history table that wasn't removed. We want a record of these records. Based on our data that would normally be a handful of rows at most.

However when the insert into #test_delete happens it inserts every single line that was deleted in the previous statement. Every single line. So if 140 records were deleted (which is our avg) #test_delete has 140 records and they are then entered into the audit table.

The timing isn't the issue here, but i will fix it.

sample data

```
t_history 
run_date                p_no  .... 
2019-01-10 10:44:47.910 31811 
2019-01-10 10:44:47.910 31817
...

#tempb 
p_no
31817
31818
31819
```

After the delete statement from the history table for run date 1-10-19, the second line should be deleted where p_no = 31817 and so on. and the first line should remain.

however what appears in #test_delete is both lines, where id = 31817 and 31811. This should not be the case. It's as though the delete statement never happened.

Comment: I don't understand after the second query, if it's delete why there would be some values in the table ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Whatever is left after whatever wasn't' deleted, and its possible something wasn't."

Comment: your query could miss records after 23:59:59.001

Comment: This is entirely too vague. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this question.

Comment: if you delete from tableA based on a selection criteria, then you query TableA with the same criteria, and find a load of records, then either the delete did not occur, the select took place before the delete, or after the delete a load more records got inserted to TableA

Comment: @Cato yes that is exactly what is happening, and that is what i'm trying to resolve. why would the delete not happen, i mean if we query the table, we clearly see the delete occurred and yet the insert has all the deleted records.

Comment: so you do the delete, then a select to confirm it and records are gone, then select into #test_delete and it fills with records?  You've not mixed it up with #tempb or anything?

Comment: We really need to see some sample data and repeatable example of this behavior. Just adding more text explanation is not really helpful.

Comment: @SeanLange done.

Comment: Logic would say that there should not be records going into the #temp file, so I don't see what repeatable data could be relevant - Are the two commands being launched asynchronously or anything?  Are the two pieces of code after each other in a script?  Are they in some sort of loop, such that query 2 could somehow be run before query 1?

Comment: @Cato, no loops (i checked) no begin/ends - one statement after another. delete first, then do an insert into temp then insert from temp into audit_log. (i should add i tried not using the #temp_delete table and just entering data using the same query into the audit log and that didnt work.

Comment: The idea is to make it easy for others to help you. The links I sent would show you that you need to provide ddl and dml. That means we can just run the code and have tables populated with data. Give us a working example and we can help. But this is just way too much effort for me at this point.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem at will, or is it something occurring only in a production run?   If you can repeat it, then try some stuff like dumping the whole of  T_HISTORY into another table after the delete, and/or put a long wait in so that you can investigate what records are there.

Comment: @Cato I will try what you suggested. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your query could miss records after 23:59:59.001 (depending on field format)

why not do

@run_date <= a.run_date and a.run_date < dateadd(day,1,@run_date)

I'm hopeful that all your objects with 'date' in the name are using date formats

Comment: I will adjust the timing, but that isn't the issue with this code. Something is still causing the insert to enter all the deleted records.

Comment: Plain and simple if you deleted rows from a table they can't possibly be inserted in a following statement, unless you have this in a transaction and are either using nolock, read uncommitted or rolled back the transaction prior to the second statement.

Comment: @SeanLange apologies for the confusion, if the table isn't a temp table T_history in this case and rows are deleted. Why would they exist? why would not existing rows be pulled in the following statement? This seems erroneous and what would i add to my code to fix this? a nolock on t_history? thats it.

Comment: Those rows cannot possibly exist after being deleted. What you are explaining is impossible.

Comment: @SeanLange that is why i'm so confused and lost. That is why I posted the ticket here. I have no idea what is happening and why the data is being inserted into my audit log table if they can't possibly exist.

Comment: Is there any ON Delete trigger or anything?

Comment: @Cato No Triggers at all